# Flymake cleanun on killing

Tags: emacs, flymake

Whenever I exit emacs flymake leaves all these temp files lying around. Is there a way to delete those even when I kill flymake and exit.

I dont want to use the hack to save files in temp folder

[Edit]

I am working in Haskell and it leaves temp files like `<filename>_flymake.hs` whenever I force close flymake process.

Comment: I've never noticed this, though I've been using [`flycheck`](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck) for a few years in place of `flymake`. Can you be more specific about the names and content of the temporary files? What language are you working in?

Comment: Hrm, "force close" sounds like the problem. Are you not able to exit Emacs normally and let `flymake` clean up after itself? If you're open to a bigger change, I urge you to try `flycheck`. It seems to require far less handholding than `flymake`, and [supports Haskell](http://flycheck.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/languages.html#haskell).